# Twisted : I cannot get the Ajax "data" parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, twisted

An ajax "POST" is triggered witht these paramaters:

```
function test22(portnb){
    console.log(portnb)
    $.ajax({url: "action",
            dataType : 'html',
            type: "POST",
            data: portnb,
            success: function( strData2 ){;
            console.log(strData2);
            $("#content3").html(strData2);
            }
    });
};
```

---

It is handled by a twisted python script:( see the interresting part below)

```
class Test3Handler(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    def render_POST(self, request):
       argo = request.content.getvalue()
       print( argo )
       retp = "<ul><li>"
       retp += argo
       retp += "</ul>"
       print (retp)
       return retp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    testHandler = TestHandler()
    test2Handler = Test2Handler()
    test3Handler = Test3Handler()
    root = static.File('/home/pi/web4')
    root.putChild('test', testHandler)
    root.putChild('test2', test2Handler)
    root.putChild('action', test3Handler)
    reactor.listenTCP(8082, server.Site(root))
    reactor.run()
```

---

The issue is that I cannot get the "data" parameter sent by Ajax ( data : portnb). the variable "argo" is empty.

I am new to Python/Ajax.
Can you help me to fix this issue?
It will be very helpful to develop something more complex later.
Thanks
Gilles

Comment: What is the value of `portnb`?

Comment: try sending it as `data: {portnb:portnb}` and get the the value as post on the other end

Answer (score 0):

portnb = 23.  When Ajax "data : {portnb}",  the python script receives "portnb = 23". I would only need to get 23, not portnb = 23. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks, Gilles

Answer (score -1):

You should set the dataType to `json` and in the data field send an object like `{ params: portnb }`

Comment: "You should set the dataType to json" — Absolutely not. The server side code is clearly returning HTML and not JSON.

Comment: "send an object like { params: portnb }" — Why? The server side code is trying to read the raw POST body. What use would URL Encoding the data be? (And that's assuming that `portnb` isn't already an object)

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
- portnb = 23 
- I would prefer to use "html" as datatype because, at the end, I would like to show it nicely in the html page.
I have done as you suggested and it works. Here is the final ajax code:

    dataType : 'html',
                type: "POST",
                data: {param : portnb},

I was working on it for mre than 1 week without success and now, it works.
Guys, you and this forum are the best.

Thanks very much
Regards,
Gilles

Comment: Just one more thing.

Comment: Just one more thing. The DATA Ajax parameter is    data: {portnb}, Portnb = 23. The "success: function( strData2 ){;"  returns : portnb=23. I only need the portnb (23) .How can I extract 23 from "portnb=23". Ideally, I would like to do it on the twisted side. I have checked the Python statements but I am lost. Do I have to use JSON?Thanks. Gilles

Comment: portnb = 23.  When Ajax "data : {portnb}",  the python script receives "portnb = 23". I would only need to get 23, not portnb = 23. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks, Gilles

Comment: I have found a way to do it using "split". portnb.split("=")[1].